# How to match characters only if preceded by (positive lookbehind)

Tags: regex

I want to match a latitude and longitude entry, separated by comma and possibly with a name:

what should match

```
-43.48394, 87.394886
-43.44884, 88.344774, home
-43.87778, 88.987566,
```

what should not match

```
-43.89987, 89.345434 home
-43.44884, 88.344774, home, restaurant
```

This is what I've tried,

```
^(-?\d+(\.\d+)?),\s*(-?\d+(\.\d+)?),?(?<=,)[a-zA-Z ]*$
```

but fails to match

```
-43.48394, 87.394886
```

what am I missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-43.48394, 87.394886` string is not matched because you require a comma to appear after a longitude value. The `,?(?<=,)` part is equal to just `,` because this pattern matches an optional comma that is followed by a position that must be preceded with a comma.

You can use

```
^(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?),\s*(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:,[a-zA-Z ]*)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/J3ZgQQ/1).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - Group 1: optional `-`, one or more digits and then an optional sequence of a dot and one or more digits
- `,`  - a comma
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - Group 2: optional `-`, one or more digits and then an optional sequence of a dot and one or more digits
- `(?:,[a-zA-Z ]*)?` - an optional sequence of a comma and then zero or more letters or spaces
- `$` - end of string.